# Appending To Slice on Struct Inside Other Slice Not Persisting

Tags: pointers, go, slice

For example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Test struct {
  elems []string
}

func main() {
  initial := Test{
    elems: make([]string, 0),
  }
  initial.elems = append(initial.elems, "apple")
  fmt.Println(initial.elems) // #1 [apple]

  s := make([]Test, 0)
  s = append(s, initial)

  initial.elems = append(initial.elems, "bannana")
  fmt.Println(initial.elems) // #2 [apple bannana]
  fmt.Println(s[0].elems) // #3 [apple]

  second := s[0]
  second.elems = append(second.elems, "carrot")
  fmt.Println(second.elems) // #4 [apple bannana]
}
```

I am looking for help understanding print statements #3 and #4. In #3 I expect `[apple bannana]` and in #4 I am expecing `[apple bannana carrot]`.

It is my understanding that the `elems` field which is a slice is automatically passed by reference and therefore each append that I do in the above block of code should modify the underlying array. But, apparently that is not the case.

So, my question is: What happens to `initial` when it gets inserted into a slice that makes this not work? Also, how would one write this code to get the expected result at print statement #4?

Comment: Slices are passed around by value.  A slice value has a pointer to the backing array, length and capacity.  Changing the slice value in initial.elems does not change the slice value in s[0].elems

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec  CTRL+F "Appending to and copying slices"

Comment: Either store pointers in the slice, or reference its contents by index.

Comment: @tike https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Golang it is mentioned:

> Map and slice values behave like pointers: they are descriptors that
>   contain pointers to the underlying map or slice data. Copying a map or
>   slice value doesn't copy the data it points to.

The way you are appending to the slice `s` is creating a new slice by adding the copy of Test struct to the `s` slice. Hence you are not setting a pointer to the original `Test` struct. So that if data changes inside the struct it will be reflected in the slice too. This is the problem you are facing.

```
  initial.elems = append(initial.elems, "apple")
  fmt.Println(initial.elems) // #1 [apple]

  s := make([]Test, 0) // this should be pointer to the struct to have teh changes in future to original struct.
  s = append(s, initial) // appending to the s slice
```

Create a pointer to the `Test` struct when making slice `s`, which will reflect the change whenever you change the elems inside original struct. For example:

```
package main
import "fmt"

type Test struct {
  elems []string
}

func main() {
  initial := Test{
    elems: make([]string, 0),
  }
  initial.elems = append(initial.elems, "apple")
  fmt.Println(initial.elems) // #1 [apple]

  s := make([]*Test, 0) // create a pointer to Test struct.
  s = append(s, &initial)

  initial.elems = append(initial.elems, "bannana")
  fmt.Println(initial.elems) // #2 [apple bannana]
  fmt.Printf("%+v\n",*s[0]) // #3 [apple banana]

  second := s[0]
  second.elems = append(second.elems, "carrot")
  fmt.Println(second.elems) // #4 [apple bannana carrot]
}
```

**Output:-**

```
[apple]
[apple bannana]
{elems:[apple bannana]}
[apple bannana carrot]
```

Working Code on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VRS6i8Xf3yE)

Comment: s := make([]*Test, 0) // create a pointer to Test struct or to slice of pointers of test struct?

Answer (score 1):

Its caused by fact, that the `initial` variable isn't the same as `s[0]` - they are two independent `Test` variables and appending to one doesn't change the second. `initial` is being copied by value to different object when passed to `append()`

Proof:

`fmt.Printf("second: %p, initial: %p\n", &second.elems[0], &initial.elems[0])`

(where `second.elems[0] == "apple"` and `initial.elems[0] == "apple"`)
outputs

`second: 0xc00000a120, initial: 0xc00000a0c0`

which shows, that this is true